# How can I deploy my C# project?

Tags: c#, deployment

How can I deploy a C# Visual Studio 2005 project so that I can run the application in another system? My project has a few dependencies and files that have to be integrated while deploying the project.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx) deployment?
It's far from perfect, but for projects without a huge amount of overhead, it's generally good enough.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know what dependencies you have.

- you need to have .Net framework installed
- you have to explicitly install all dependencies that you used from the GAC on your target machine (some 3rd party components)
- and then you just need to copy files from your \bin\Release folder
- install all services, etc. if you have any

In the simplest cases only copying files should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the project file in visual studio and publish to a different location. This will build the site and copy it to the specified directory.

Also, if you need to do anything extra during the build, you can specify custom build actions on the build tab of the project's properties.

EDIT: now that I see you added that it's a windows application my answer doesn't matter.  I'd try adding a setup and deployment project in visual studio to handle installing/deploying your windows application.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of project?

Assuming it's a regular winforms application, just copy everything from either the obj\debug or obj\release directory to the new computer.  Then run your executable

Comment: but the obj\debug does have the dlls that i have referred. how can i add my referenced dlls and deploy the project.

Comment: Go to properties on the referenced dlls and make sure that the Copy Local property is set to true.  After rebuild, VS will copy the files to the debug directory.

Answer (score 1):

You more or less have three options (maybe 4?) as I see it.

1. [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hb0zwz8(VS.80).aspx)
2. [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey(VS.80).aspx)
3. Just distribute
   the exe itself

In your particular case I would suggest ClickOnce as long as the project is not massive with too many dependencies.

For other [alternatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54cw8ks0(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The right answer depends on many criteria.

The simplest way to deploy is by copying files.  Just put your .exe, the dependent .dll's, and the .config file in a directory and copy it onto the target machine.  It's simple, but there are many restrictions to this approach:

- It assumes that the target machine has the right version of the .NET framework installed
- It assumes a certain technical competence on the part of the person installing the software.
- The installation won't do basic things like create start menu items.

Publishing the program for ClickOnce deployment addresses a lot of these issues, but it's got its own set of limitations.  I haven't used it much, so there are probably more than these, though these alone are pretty significant:

- Programs are installed into the ClickOnce cache, not the Program Files directory.
- If your program does anything outside of the ClickOnce sandbox, you have to deal with security elevation and code signing.

You can create a VS Setup and Deployment project and build an .msi file to install the program.  The most obvious drawback to this is that it's complicated:  .msi files can do many, many things, and the Setup and Deployment object model is complex, with  documentation that is, let us say, fanciful.  But there are things you can do with .msi installation that you can't readily do with other approaches, including (and *certainly* not limited to):

- Cleanly uninstall the program through Add/Remove Programs.
- Provide an actual UI for installation that lets the user decide where to put the program.
- Support scripted installation via MSIEXEC.
- Install components besides the program, e.g. databases, COM objects, etc.
- Put components in the target machine's GAC.